# Jest Folder Structure

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I'm currently employing the use of Jest in my CRA application. I see that CRA opted for the use of `filename.test.js` format when writing tests but I find this approach a bit cumbersome on the eyes and brain. I found out that you can write tests in a folder named `__tests__` and jest will automatically run the tests in that folder. I like this approach. My question now is, what is the standard when using this setup? Usually, my `src` folder is set up as such:

```
src
└── components
    ├── some1ComponentDir
    └── some2ComponentDir
```

Do I create a `__tests__` folder at each level or do I mock the structure of my `src` folder inside of my `__tests__` folder located inside the `src` folder?

If you think this is a silly question, please just ignore it and move on. Thanks for any help.

Comment: In Enterprise Application,mostly peopel write unit test cases within same folder where code is places.you should write all test cases in Single __test__ directory

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN ok. I'm curious if the test directory would mock the structure of the files it's testing.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The conventions for Jest, in order of best to worst in my opinion:

1. `src/file.test.js` mentioned first in the [Getting Started](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started) docs, and is great for keeping tests (especially unit) easy to find next to source files
2. `src/__tests__/file.js` lets you have multiple `__tests__` directories so tests are still near original files without cluttering the same directories
3. `__tests__/file.js` more like older test frameworks that put all the tests in a separate directory; while Jest does support it, it's not as easy to keep tests organized and discoverable

Since you don't want 1, it sounds like 2 is your best option.

Comment: Just curious: best/worst in what sense?

Comment: Good question, I've updated the answer with my opinions.

Comment: I'd like to add that at least in my opinion number 3 is justified to be at 3. It's quite cumbersome to keep the structure of the test folder the same as that of the source folder, especially for deeply nested directories. The imports at the start of all test files become extremely difficult to read and locate.

Comment: It's also easier to keep your source code unit/integration tested when the tests are close by. 1 gets you the most colocation and 3 gets you the least.

Comment: @NickMcCurdy are test.js will get attcah in build folder.

Comment: Are you asking if Jest will run tests in `build`?

Comment: If you are using  the `file.test.js` pattern for the test names, then the directory doesn't need the underscores -- jest will find `tests/file.test.js`.  That helps readability imho.

Comment: Yes, but I think it's best to follow Jest's naming conventions to make intentions clear. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I think the advantage to option 3 is that it ensures that you don't ship test code out with application code. It also makes it easier to keep your application code from referencing test code.

Comment: I disagree. `__tests__` is still in the path so it's still easy to see an accidental import or automate searching for them. The same applies for `.test.`

Answer (score 6):

A testing folder structure I like:

```
src / __tests__ 
          ├── components
          │       ├── componentOne.test.js
          │       ├── componentTwo.test.js
          │       └── .....
          ├── functions  
          │       ├── functionOne.test.js
          │       ├── functionTwo.test.js
          │       └── .....
          ├── ....
```

Comment: Can you please suggest: Where to keep the mock directory?